# codenameone autocomplete text field display issue in gui

Tags: codenameone

I m working on my mobile apps using codename1 and i found that after adding an autocomplete textfield to any form, every other component disapears along with tabs behind a white container.

Comment: I can t reproduce the problem with other projects though, the configurations of the theme might caused this. I just can t figure out which config is the reason behind this

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot, how do you layout the components in the UI? Are you using the GUI builder or handcoded application? Can you provide a screenshot of he fully expanded Component Inspector?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a scrollable [FlowLayout](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/layouts/FlowLayout.html) (which is the default layout manager) and some nesting behavior goes bad.

Another guess is that you add everything into the layered pane which is a HUGE MISTAKE, you should add everything to the form directly or content pane.

Comment: I just added four screenshots to my post. I tried borderlayout and tablelayout, same issue. I think it's due to the configurations i ve done on the theme (a constant maybe) because it occurs only for autocomplete component.